# My calculator function doesn't allow for decimals

Tags: javascript

My calculator works fine with integers, it rejects a number with a decimal place i.e. 2.34.

Here is the full calculator with HTML and JS.

```
    <div class="module-border-wrap">
        <div class="module">
    <form id="main">
        <label for="rprice">Retail Price: </label>
        <input type="number" id="rprice" ><br><br>
        <label for="cogoods">Cost of Goods: </label>
        <input type="number" id="cogoods" ><br><br>        
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
    </form>
    </div>
        </div>
        <div id="display">
            <p> </p>
        </div>
    
<script>
    let retailPrice = document.getElementById("rprice");
    let costOfGoods = document.getElementById("cogoods");
    let form = document.getElementById("main");
form.addEventListener("submit",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(calculate());
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = calculate();
});
function calculate (){
    let difference = retailPrice.value - costOfGoods.value
    return retailPrice.value / difference 
 };
</script>
```

Comment: what the type of the input fields? can you share your html code?

Comment: Could you please put your code into a runnable snippet using the snippet tool in the question editor?  It would help demonstrate the problem to have a fully working repro.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form id=main>
  <input type=number step=0.01 placeholder="retail price" id=rprice />
  <input type=number step=0.01 placeholder=cost id=cogoods />
  <input type=submit />
</form>
<div id=display></div>
<script>
  let form = document.getElementById("main");
  form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(calculate());
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = calculate();
  });

  function calculate() {
    let retailPrice = document.getElementById("rprice");
    let costOfGoods = document.getElementById("cogoods");
    let difference = Number(retailPrice.value) - Number(costOfGoods.value)
    return retailPrice.value / difference
  };
</script>
```